# Android In-app billing purchase - Item not found

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have implemented In-app Billing V3 with this [plugin](https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling/tree/master/v3) for phonegap.
When I purchase my item, google play returns the following

```
The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found
```

This is most probably a setup issue somewhere, but I can't find what could be the problem.

This is what I have done so far:

- Item created on google play and active with a price
- Queried Item ID is the same as the one on google play
- Uploaded my apk in the alpha channel ( also tried beta channel), it is in 'Draft in Alpha' status
- Waited few hours ( 48h! )
- Used a different gmail account to test the purchase
- Test account email address is in the Licence white list
- Also created a google group and added the test user in it
- Tested the app on two differents devices
- APK signed and uploaded google play. Same version is installed on the device
- Tried With Managed and Unmanaged products
- Purchased item android.test.purchased works
- The billing key in the configuration is the same as the one on google play
- Google Play version on device: 4.8.20

**Here is the stack I have from logcat, strange error at the end, not sure if it is related:**

```
    D/CordovaLog(32254): file:///android_asset/www/plugins/com.smartmobilesoftware.inappbilling/www/inappbilling.js: Line 6 : InAppBilling[js]: setup ok
    I/Web Console(32254): InAppBilling[js]: setup ok:6
    D/CORDOVA_BILLING(32254): init start
    D/CORDOVA_BILLING(32254): Creating IAB helper.
    D/CORDOVA_BILLING(32254): Starting setup.
    D/IabHelper(32254): Starting in-app billing setup.
    W/PluginManager(32254): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to InAppBillingPlugin.init blocked the main thread for 21ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
    D/IabHelper(32254): Billing service connected.
    D/IabHelper(32254): Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
    D/Finsky  (32296): [2476] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.montreal.deps: Account from first account - [sdkNy9OtgBRMmwDfMof3YGfedjA]
    D/IabHelper(32254): In-app billing version 3 supported for com.montreal.deps
    D/Finsky  (32296): [2451] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.montreal.deps: Account from first account - [sdkNy9OtgBRMmwDfMof3YGfedjA]
    D/IabHelper(32254): Subscriptions AVAILABLE.
    D/CORDOVA_BILLING(32254): Setup finished.
    D/CORDOVA_BILLING(32254): Setup successful. Querying inventory.
    D/IabHelper(32254): Starting async operation: refresh inventory
    D/IabHelper(32254): Querying owned items, item type: inapp
    D/IabHelper(32254): Package name: com.montreal.deps
    D/IabHelper(32254): Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
    D/Finsky  (32296): [2450] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.montreal.deps: Account from first account - [sdkNy9OtgBRMmwDfMof3YGfedjA]
    D/Finsky  (32296): [2450] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.montreal.deps: Account from first account - [sdkNy9OtgBRMmwDfMof3YGfedjA]
    D/IabHelper(32254): Owned items response: 0
    D/IabHelper(32254): Continuation token: null
    D/IabHelper(32254): Querying SKU details.
    D/IabHelper(32254): queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.
    D/IabHelper(32254): Querying owned items, item type: subs
    D/IabHelper(32254): Package name: com.montreal.deps
    D/IabHelper(32254): Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
    D/Finsky  (32296): [2476] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.montreal.deps: Account from first account - [sdkNy9OtgBRMmwDfMof3YGfedjA]
    D/Finsky  (32296): [2476] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.montreal.deps: Account from first account - [sdkNy9OtgBRMmwDfMof3YGfedjA]
    D/IabHelper(32254): Owned items response: 0
    D/IabHelper(32254): Continuation token: null
    D/IabHelper(32254): Querying SKU details.
    D/IabHelper(32254): queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.
    D/IabHelper(32254): Ending async operation: refresh inventory
    D/CORDOVA_BILLING(32254): Inside mGotInventoryListener
    D/CORDOVA_BILLING(32254): Query inventory was successful.
    D/CordovaLog(32254): file:///android_asset/www/plugins/com.smartmobilesoftware.inappbilling/www/inappbilling.js: Line 6 : InAppBilling[js]: buy called!
    I/Web Console(32254): InAppBilling[js]: buy called!:6
    D/IabHelper(32254): Starting async operation: launchPurchaseFlow
    D/IabHelper(32254): Constructing buy intent for deps.item.test, item type: inapp
    D/Finsky  (32296): [2451] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.montreal.deps: Account from first account - [sdkNy9OtgBRMmwDfMof3YGfedjA]
    D/Finsky  (32296): [2451] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.montreal.deps: Account from first account - [sdkNy9OtgBRMmwDfMof3YGfedjA]
    D/Finsky  (32296): [2451] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.montreal.deps: Account from first account - [sdkNy9OtgBRMmwDfMof3YGfedjA]
    D/IabHelper(32254): Launching buy intent for deps.item.test. Request code: 10001
    W/PluginManager(32254): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to InAppBillingPlugin.buy blocked the main thread for 28ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
    D/CordovaActivity(32254): Paused the application!
    D/CordovaWebView(32254): Handle the pause
    D/FirewallPolicy( 2119): getURLFilterEnabled(true)
    D/FirewallPolicy( 2119): isUrlBlocked - Policy disabled
    D/WebView (32254): loadUrlImpl: called
    D/webcore (32254):  CORE loadUrl: called
    D/webkit  (32254): Firewall not null
    D/FirewallPolicy( 2119): getURLFilterEnabled(true)
    D/FirewallPolicy( 2119): isUrlBlocked - Policy disabled
    D/webkit  (32254): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
    D/FirewallPolicy( 2119): getURLFilterEnabled(true)
    D/FirewallPolicy( 2119): isUrlBlocked - Policy disabled
    I/ClipboardServiceEx( 2119): Send intent for dismiss clipboard dialog inside hideCurrentInputLocked() !
    D/WindowManager( 2119): PhoneWindowManager: focusChangedLw
    D/KeyguardViewMediator( 2119): setHidden false
    D/CordovaLog(32254): file:///android_asset/www/app/js/controllers/payment.js: Line 12 : response then payment
    I/Web Console(32254): response then payment:12
    D/CordovaLog(32254): file:///android_asset/www/app/js/controllers/payment.js: Line 13 : OK
    I/Web Console(32254): OK:13
    D/Finsky  (32296): [1] CarrierParamsAction.createCarrierBillingParameters: Carrier billing config is null. Device is not targeted for DCB 2.
    E/Finsky  (32296): [2472] FileBasedKeyValueStore.delete: Attempt to delete 'paramsopT-pzzx02i69KNTNDgLqg' failed!
```

Many thanks if you find the problem as I have been fighting with it for few days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APKs in draft status do no longer work for testing in-app billing. You need to release it in the alpha or beta channel.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#draft_apps

Comment: Thanks, it pointed me out in the right direction. I basically had to publish the apk. By clicking on publish I thought it would publish it to production, playstore UI is not really clear

Comment: @Hans Kratz by release do you mean publishing the app with all the required assets like icon,screenshots and all that.if so then will it be available publicly to all,if no then please elaborate more